# Match string with hex string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm converting some of my code from C++, and wanted to take advantage of Regex for a scenario in my program. The user story says that the string needs to be 3 sets of hex numbers between 4 tags (however these tags didn't have end tags *sigh*) The 4 tags to be used were `<DIV>`, `<GKY>`, `<UID>`, `<END>` well I like to give my users a little more flexibility in their code if they so desire, so what I was hoping for a simple regex expression that I could write a simple method around. I found the code I wanted to match if it is a hex string ( think I do atleast), but i can't get my Reg expression test tool to match with a tag behind it. Take this string for example.

`<DIV>A9F81123C8288B34758D0481E8271843<GKY><UID><END>`

I wouldn't mind if the regex expression returned `<DIV>A9...` or if it return just the hex string. but I would want it to be able to return it from all 3 of these scenarios

- `<DIV>A9F81123C8288B34758D0481E8271843<GKY><UID><END>`
- `<GKY><DIV>A9F81123C8288B34758D0481E8271843<UID><END>`
- `<GKY><UID><DIV>A9F81123C8288B34758D0481E8271843<END>`

a full key example would look something like this

`<DIV>A9F81123C8288B34758D0481E8271843<GKY>1234568790ABCDEF0<UID>0422ABCDEF<END>`

so far all I have in my unit test is to tell that the string contains the 4 Tags. So i'm stuck right here

```
    public static KeyInputParser ParseKeyInputString(string inputKey)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputKey)) throw new ArgumentNullException("inputKey", "Input Key can't be null or empty");
        inputKey = inputKey.ToUpper();
        var key = new KeyInputParser();
        AssertKeyContainsTheseTags(inputKey, "<DIV>", "<GKY>", "<UID>", "<END>");

        //DIV must always be 16 bytes
        string div = Regex.Match(inputKey, @"<DIV>^([A-Fa-f0-9]{2}){16}$").Value;
        //UID can be 5, 7, or 10 bytes
        //not sure on GKY but it must be more than 1 byte
        return key;
    }
```

div is returning empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not really care about tags themselves, you can try this:

```
(?<=>)[A-Fa-f0-9]+(?=<)
```

It correctly matches all your test cases, see it in action on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/Fx9jArqXag).

If you want the preceding tag as well, this is ok (preview [here](http://rubular.com/r/QP1xOVpyQU)):

```
(?<tag><\w+>)(?<string>[A-Fa-f0-9]+)(?=<)
```

Comment: Rubular is one cool site. I think I'm going to be trying your method out, however It would seem that C# and ruby have a slightly different syntax

Comment: @RobertSnyder they should work though, I have copied the syntax from the .NET regex reference because I didn't remember it ;) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you were correct about the syntax ( i just didn't know that you were naming the groups with tag and string. once I figured that out I had a big ol smile on my face.

Answer (score 1):

```
string div = Regex.Match(inputKey, @"<DIV>([A-Fa-f0-9]{32})").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work for you:

```
^((?<gdiv><DIV>[A-Fa-f0-9]*)|(?<ggky><GKY>[A-Fa-f0-9]*)|(?<guid><UID>[A-Fa-f0-9]*))*<END>$
```

Tests:

```
input:   <DIV>A9F81123C8288B34758D0481E8271843<GKY><UID><END>
matches: gdiv   <DIV>A9F81123C8288B34758D0481E8271843
         ggky   <GKY>
         guid   <UID>

input:   <GKY><DIV>A9F81123C8288B34758D0481E8271843<UID><END>
matches: gdiv   <DIV>A9F81123C8288B34758D0481E8271843
         ggky   <GKY>
         guid   <UID>

input:   <GKY><UID><DIV>A9F81123C8288B34758D0481E8271843<END>
matches: gdiv   <DIV>A9F81123C8288B34758D0481E8271843
         ggky   <GKY>
         guid   <UID>

input:   <UID>0422ABCDEF<DIV>A9F81123C8288B34758D0481E8271843<GKY>1234568790ABCDEF0<END>
matches: gdiv   <DIV>A9F81123C8288B34758D0481E8271843
         ggky   <GKY>1234568790ABCDEF0
         guid   <UID>0422ABCDEF

input:   <GKY>1234568790ABCDEF0<DIV>A9F81123C8288B34758D0481E8271843<UID>0422ABCDEF<END>
matches: gdiv   <DIV>A9F81123C8288B34758D0481E8271843
         ggky   <GKY>1234568790ABCDEF0
         guid   <UID>0422ABCDEF
```

See examples at [rebular](http://rubular.com/r/RMDs4LLBzb).

**NOTE:**

While one of tags (`DIV`, `GKY`, or `UID`) values may be empty, so I would recommend you to use `[A-Fa-f0-9]*` instead of -for example- `[A-Fa-f0-9]{16}` and test length of values by your self.